# IMG tag inside a VIDEO tag

Tags: html5-video, semantic-markup

If you check out facebook.com/paper you'll find  several `<video><img/></video>`.

I want to know if this is a semantic/SEO friendly fallback to `video` tag or if it is just a hack for older browser. `poster` attributes is not enough for modern browser? Is it a mobile device hack?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `track`/`source` elements, the content of `video` is for user agents that don’t support `video`.

[From HTML5 (CR)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element):

> Content may be provided inside the `video` element. User agents should not show this content to the user; it is intended for older Web browsers which do not support `video`, so that legacy video plugins can be tried, or to show text to the users of these older browsers informing them of how to access the video contents.

So supporting user agents (i.e., modern browsers) should ignore this.

Comment: its not a hack...its to support non-compliant user agents so the user isn't staring at a blank box